# Is there a library in java that can accept future task?

Tags: java, open-source

I am looking for java library or open source that will do the following:
Accept a `Runnable` task, and a specific time to execute it in the future, and execute it then.
Do you know such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like scheduler? Try [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) (doesn't use `Runnable` but `Job`).

Or try Java's [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `java.util.Timer` class to run a `java.util.TimerTask`. TimerTask imlements the Runnable interface

Answer (score 0):

Its already there in your standard JDK: **TimerTask**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the software or the code you need but if it's just running a task you need then you could probably use CRON for *nix based systems and Task Scheduler for Windows.